# How to associate custom content type with external application in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, content-type

I've been looking for a solution to this for years. I still cannot figure out how the hell Firefox does this and how to implement the same behavior in Chrome.

I have a web application that allows me to open files locally using my preferred editor. 
A PHP script receives a file path and line and then sends the following output:

```
<?
header('Content-type: application/x-file-and-line');
echo $_GET['file'] . "\n" . $_GET['line'];
?>
```

Which results in Firefox magically opening that file in the specified line with using my IDE.
I cannot find the place where this is specified. Any ideas? Obviously I did not do that.

That's not all. I want to implement the same in Chrome but I keep reading that's not possible. How's that? Can that at least be emulated using an extension or editing a config file myself? I don't want to run a server locally to handle that since it's non-straightforward.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTTP response headers to that request? I can't find anything regarding this `x-file-and-line`on the web or in firefox's source.

Comment: This is a custom content type specifically used to open files locally related to a private company's web application.
My question focuses on how to handle custom content types, not just that one.

Comment: I'm not sure you can override how the browser handles content types from an web app. I'm thinking you'd probably need to do this in an browser extension. Another approach could be a custom protocol handler.

Comment: A protocol handler needs a URL to handle it. I cannot execute a process in the user machine that way...